Android App in repository of a bigger project
Myself and two others are working on a small project together which consists of a Server, a Website and a Mobile app. We want all of it to be in one repository and have already started with the server and website now we want to add the app but cant figure out how to include it and still be able to execute it via Android Studio.
We have tried importing the app as a new Module, which had and "Unresolved refference: libs" error.
* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 3:     alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
                    ^ Unresolved reference: libs

  Line 4:     alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
                    ^ Unresolved reference: libs

2 errors

We now tried to just create a new project inside the already existing folder which seams to work but has the problem that we cant start the app in the "outer folder" only inside the app folder and the git functions (like updating/committing/pushing etc provided by android Studio) dont work inside the app folder.
We have done some research but have not found anything other than importing it as a Module (like detailed above).
Is there a way to get this to work?

Have you considered using submodules? Would that work for your use case?

Is that a gradle file error? If yes then post that file and important reference variable declarations if needed so that others can understand your project structure properly.
